# How get id from another model odoo

Tags: odoo

can i get id from a field m2o of a model in another model before saving (before create) because both models will be created at the same time.

```
class Contrat(models.Model):
contrat_parent_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.contrat', string='Numéro Contrat Client')

class Lot(models.Model):
contrat_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.contrat', ondelete='cascade')
articlecontrat_ids = fields.Many2many('facturation.articleouvrage',string='Article Lot')
```

get id of contrat_parent_id in model Lot before create both models(contrat,lot)
when I change contrat_parent_id thanks for your help